# How to solve for a distribution function over which another function is integrated?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

How to solve for a distribution function $F$ in:

$$T(x) = \int_a^x p(y) dF(y)$$

Let me provide you with the following example.  A company may advertise a price in range between $[a,x]$ for its product. $F(y)$ stands for a probability that the company advertises a price smaller than or equal to $y$ ($y \in [a,x]$), and greater than $a$. $p(y)$ is the proportion of consumers (which can be assumed as a unity mass) to which the advertisement of price $y$ reaches; obviously, $0 \leq p(y) \leq 1.$  Finally, $T(x)$ is the probability that a particular consumer observes an ad offering a price $x$ or lower (and greater than $a$).

Given the above equation, how to solve for $F$ in terms of $T()$ and $p()$ for $y \in [a,x]$?

Comment: Welcome to Maht.SE ! your question is in its presents form, impossible to understand. You shoudl provide more details about what you mean by solving, what are $b(x)$ and $T(x)$ and what you have attempted to find the solution. You won't get any answer unless you do this.

Comment: @Tom-tom, thanks a lot for the comment.  I edited the question to make it easier to understand.  Also the question probably relates to statistics, but I assumed that I can ask it here

Comment: You mean $T(x)=\int_a^x p(y)dF(y)$. The nice case for this is when $F$ is absolutely continuous (i.e. the price random variable has a density) and $p$ is continuous and never vanishes. Then $T'=pf$, so $f=T'/p$, so $F=\int_a^xT'(y)/p(y)dy$.

Comment: When $F$ is pure discrete and $p$ is continuous and doesn't vanish where $F$ has jumps, everything is also OK: the jumps in $F$ are equal to the jumps in $T$ divided by the corresponding values of $p$. By linearity everything is *still* OK when $F$ just has no singular part: just handle the continuous and discrete parts separately. I don't know what to do if there is a singular part, though.

Comment: @Ian, thank you very much for the detailed explanation!!

Comment: Thank you for editing the question. There is still a point that I don't get : why does $T$ depend on $x$, since $x$ is the integration variable on the right-hand side. Shouldn't it be written as $T[F]=\int_a^bp(x)\mathrm dF(x)$ ?

Comment: @Tom-Tom, you are right. My apologies for the confusion. As Ian pointed out, it should be $T(x) = \int_a^x p(y) dF(y)$

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of functional optimization. $T$ depends on $F$ and $p$ is given (or at least could be known using polls).

Let us first follow @Ian's comment by assuming that $F$ is absolutely continuous. This means that $\mathrm d F(y)=f(y)\mathrm dy$, where $f$ is the probability density of the price. As $T$ depends not on a single variable, but on all the values of $f$, one uses the notation $T[f]=\int_a^xp(y)f(y)\mathrm dy$. Let us consider $\delta f$ an arbitrary function satisfying $$\int_a^x\delta f(y)\mathrm dy=0\tag 1$$ (to ensure the normalization of $f+\delta f$). 
If $f$ is the optimal price probability, the quantity $T[f+\delta f]-T[f]$ must be negative for *any* function $\delta f$. Now we should notice that $T[f+\delta f]-T[f]=T[\delta f]$. This does not depend on $f$ ! In this case, there is a solution only if $p(y)=\frac1{x-a}$ is the uniform distribution. In any other case, one can find a function $\delta f$ satisfying (1) and $T[\delta f]>0$. (take any function satisfying (1) such that $\operatorname{sign}\left(\delta f(y)\right)=\operatorname{sign}\left(p(y)-\frac1{x-a}\right)$.)
So we have a first solution:

**If $p$ is a uniform distribution, any choice of $F$ is optimal.**

In a second case, if $p$ is not uniform, we have shown that $F$ cannot be continuous. Let us concentrate on the discontinuities and chose $F$ as steps
$$F(y)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\Theta(y-y_i)\tag 2 $$
where $y_i\in[a,x]$, $a_i>0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^Na_i=1$. Therefore 
$$T=\sum_{i=1}^Na_ip(y_i).$$
If $p$ reaches its absolute maximum on $[a,x]$ at point $y_{\mathrm m}$, then the maximum of $T$ is reached for $N=1$, $y_1=y_{\mathrm m}$ (and $a_1=1$). If the absolute maximum of $p$ is reached at several values
of $y$, any solution of the form (2) with $y_i$ equal to these values is optimal. This is the optimal solution because if $F$ grows between to discontinuities, this will result in diminishing the coeffients $a_i$.

**If $p$ is not uniform, the optimal solution are $F$ of the form** 
(2) **where the discontinuities are located where $p$ reaches its absolute maximum**.

In a way, a uniform distribution reaches its absolute maximum everywhere, so the two cases merge.

**Note** Few words concerning the income function $P=\int yp(y)\mathrm dF(y)$ : the reasoning is the same except that the function $p$ is replaced by $q(y)=yp(y)$. The "reference" function is therefore not the uniform distribution but $p(y)=1/y$. For this function, any choice of $F$ is optimal. Otherwise, apply the same reasoning with the discontinuities and locate the absolute maximum of $q$ on $[a,x]$. Example: if $p(y)=A\exp(-y/y_0)$, the optimal price is $\max\left\{\min\{x,y_0\},a\right\}$.